# provide a download link PDF TICKET on the order confirmation page

Tags: woocommerce

I work on a project with woocommmerce for a site that sells tickets online I use the fooevent plugin. I would like when a person buys a ticket that he can download it directly on the woocommerce confirmation page. I used the following code for downloading tickets but it does not work

```
<h1><?php esc_attr_e( 'Tickets', 'fooevents-pdf-tickets' ); ?></h1>
<table>

<?php foreach ( $tickets as $ticket ) : ?>
<?php $product_id = get_post_meta( $ticket->ID, 'WooCommerceEventsProductID', true ); ?>  
    <?php $woocommerce_events_ticket_id = get_post_meta( $ticket->ID, 'WooCommerceEventsTicketID', true ); ?>
    <?php $woocommerce_events_ticket_hash = get_post_meta( $ticket->ID, 'WooCommerceEventsTicketHash', true ); ?>
    <?php $ticket_path = ''; ?>
    <?php if ( ! empty( $woocommerce_events_ticket_hash ) ) : ?>
        <?php $ticket_path = $this->config->pdf_ticket_url . $woocommerce_events_ticket_hash . '-' . $woocommerce_events_ticket_id . '-' . $woocommerce_events_ticket_hash . '-' . $woocommerce_events_ticket_id . '.pdf'; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <?php $ticket_path = $this->config->pdf_ticket_url . $woocommerce_events_ticket_id . '-' . $woocommerce_events_ticket_id . '.pdf'; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo esc_attr( $ticket->post_title ); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo esc_attr( get_the_title( $product_id ) ); ?></td>
        <td><a href="<?php echo esc_attr( $ticket_path ); ?>" target="_BLANK"><?php esc_attr_e( 'Download', 'fooevents-pdf-tickets' ); ?></a></td>
    </tr> <?php endforeach; ?></table>
```